# Does MPI_File_write_at() initialize the file with zeros?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, hexdump, parallel-io

Consider the following simple program which writes the rank of all processes whos rank is bigger than zero into a file:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_rank, world_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    MPI_Offset offset;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File fh;

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "myfile", MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
            MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
    
    offset = world_rank * sizeof(int);

    if (world_rank > 0) {
        MPI_File_write_at(fh, offset, &world_rank, 1, MPI_INT, &status);
    }

    MPI_File_close(&fh);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

we compiled and run it on 4 processes

```
mpic++ main.cpp
mpirun --oversubscribe -n 4 a.out
```

We check the written file with `hexdump -C myfile`

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |................|
00000010
```

Now, I never made a write call to the first integer aka the first 4 bytes but they are zero.

Can I be **sure** that those are always zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_File_write_at` will write the data into the file as `binary data`. Then when you run the command `hexdump -C myfile` that command will display the data, accordingly, with the first `4 bytes` being the *offset*. Those, first bytes are not part of the binary data *per si*, but rather added by `hexdump -C myfile` for readability purposes.

The hexadecimal `00000010` represents `10000` in binary and `16` in decimal. If you look at your first line, ignoring the first 4 bytes,:

```
  4 bytes   4 bytes      4 bytes      4 bytes       4 bytes 
00000000 | 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00   03 00 00 00
00000010 |
```

You have `16` (4x4) bytes, hence why the next row starts with `00000010`.

> Can I be sure that those are always zero?

As far as the standard is concerned, I have not found there, explicitly stating that if one skips the beginning of the file `offset > 0`, that the MPI implementation will fill that *gap* with zeros. For instance, with the MPI version (Open MPI 1.8.8) that I am using, if I modify your code to:

```
 if (world_rank == 3) {
    MPI_File_write_at(fh, offset, &world_rank, 1, MPI_INT, &status);
}
```

I get the following output from `hexdump -C myfile`:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |................|
00000010
```

So with the MPI version that I am using, and apparently with yours, it initializes with zeros.

Nonetheless, unless a reliable source can be found (which I did not managed to find one) that explicitly states that in your case the first 4 bytes will always be zero, I would advice to not make any assumptions on that regard. Notwithstanding,  one should not *care* about the file content *part* that was not written by processes, anyway.

**EDIT:** A clarification from "the Open MPI mailing list":

> In general, the contents of a file written by the MPI IO interface are
> going to be implementation-specific.